# How to show that the polynomials $1,x,x^2...x^n$ are linearly independent in $P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that the polynomials $1,x,x^2...x^n$ are linearly independent in $P_n$, I don't understand the proof using FTA(Fundamental theorem of algebra)

Comment: What is FTA? Other than that, note that one formally declares a polynomial $P=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ to be zero exactly if all of its coefficients are zero, i.e. $P=0$ if and only if $a_i=0$ for all $i$. 

If you think about a polynomial as a function (say from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R})$ this makes a lot of sense: indeed, $P$ is a zero function exactly when $P(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, plugging in enough different values of $x$ you'll get a huge system of linear equations in the coefficients, from that one readily concludes that all coefficients need to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If they are linearly dependent then $a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^{n}=0$ **for all** $x$ for some coefficients $a_i$ not all of which are $0$. But a polynomial can only have finite number of zeros unless it is the zero polynomial. Hence we must have $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: In fact, if the above polynomial is $\,0\,$ at $\,n+1\,$ different arguments then indeed it is the $\,0$-polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you specified that FTA is the *Fundamental theorem of algebra*, consider the equation:
$$a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^{n}=0$$
The polynomials $1,x,x^2…x^n$ are linearly independent if the previous equality **only** holds *for all $x$* if all the coefficients $a_i$ are zero. By the FTA, a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ (real) roots, so...